# Imprecision of ASM jump instructions observed in debugger

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, machine-code, ollydbg

I am making some inline modifications to an application in OllyDbg and am noticing some strange behavior.

These are the instructions I wrote, copied directly from the debugger:

```
2005FE35   4C               DEC ESP
2005FE36   77 21            JA SHORT 2005FE59 ; 23 byte difference
```

To be clear, I only modified the opcodes (4C 77 21); everything else is automatically interpreted by OllyDbg, and therein lies my confusion. The instructions are supposed to decrement the ESP register and then perform a conditional jump forward by 21 hex bytes. However, the difference between addresses 0x2005FE59 and 0x2005FE36 is not 21 - it's 23!

Playing around with the 21 hex byte value, I observed seemingly erratic results.

```
2005FE36   77 20            JA SHORT 2005FE58 ; 22 byte difference
2005FE36   77 19            JA SHORT 2005FE51 ; 1B byte difference
2005FE36   77 17            JA SHORT 2005FE4F ; 19 byte difference
```

The number of hex bytes I instruct to jump forward does not match the address offset; it seems to be always off by 2.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jump (or any instruction) is executed after the instruction is read and IP is incremented by the instruction's size (2 bytes) so the jump is relative to `2005FE38`.

Comment: That would explain things. Much obliged!

Comment: @AK-33 standard basic CPU fetch/execute cycle is (1) fetch instruction from IP (n bytes), (2) increment IP by n bytes, (3) execute instruction.